# Angular Navigation Start not working as the loading image continues to spin

Tags: angular

I was in need of showing a loading image when the component gets the data after using the Resolve. But the problem is that I am getting the loading image in the start and it continues as it is because the NavigationStart and the NavigationEnd doesn't work.

Component code:

```js
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        public commonService: CommonService,
        private modalService: NgbModal,
        private appService: AppService,
        private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute
    
      ) {
      
        debugger;
        this.router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: Event) => {
    
          if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
            this.showloadingIndicator = true;
          }
    
          if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            this.showloadingIndicator = false;
          }
    
        });
      }
```

html code snippet:

```html
    <div *ngIf="showloadingIndicator" class="spinner">LOADING</div>
```

Routing:

```js
    const routes: Routes = [
        {
            path: '',
            component: HomeComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'dashboard',
                    component: DashboardComponent,
                    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                    resolve: {
                        results: RouteResolver,
                        graphs: GraphsRouteResolver
                    }
                },
    
                { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
                { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            ],
        },
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check add the below condition, it seems one of your resolver doesn't resolve properly, it might be throwing an error. Check the console or add the error handling in the resolver.

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    public commonService: CommonService,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    private appService: AppService,
    private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute

  ) {
  
    debugger;   // remove this and try to add break points in the browser developer tool, it is a good practice
    this.router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: Event) => {

      if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.showloadingIndicator = true;
      }

      if (
           routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd ||
           routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel ||
           routerEvent instanceof NavigationError
       ) {
        this.showloadingIndicator = false;
      }

    });
  }
```